# Is it necessary to have the UDP port open for an Ethereum private net?

Tags: private-blockchain, network, node-discovery, firewalls

An Ethereum node requires both TCP (listener) and UDP (discovery) port (usually 30303) open and reachable by other nodes.

My question: is it possible to run a private network with my node only reachable by the peers via TCP port 30303, if those peers configure my node as a `bootnode`?

```
geth --bootnodes "enode://myID@myIP:30303"
```

Or will the peers drop my bootnode if only it's TCP but not the UDP port 30303 is reachable?

<sub>(edit: tried running it with TCP only and it seemed to work fine, so just want to make sure I don't miss anything)</sub>